# implementing hashing with random access files java

Tags: java, hash

I am implementing hashing with random access files in java to treat collisions. I need to use a method to generate the keys according to a name to try to minimize collisions. With the method that I have, if income 100 records, I generated 95 collisions.

Note that the hash method I use is that of division or modulo the input data string is of length 6.

Are there possible improvements to this method, or alternatives?

```
public int hashCode(String nombre )  {
    int hash = 1;
    hash =  hash*31 + nombre.hashCode();
    System.out.println("hsh " +hash);
    return Math.abs(hash);
}
```

Comment: guide to improve the method or recommend new one?

Comment: Note: The String.hashCode() is not great for this purpose. We have implemented something which does this in Java, but have looked at a number of alternatives http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2015/08/comparing-hashing-strategies.html

Comment: My recommendation is to use a open source implementation which does this already ;) or at least read the code so you can learn from it. It's not as simple as you might imagine.

Comment: How many buckets do you have?  The most buckets, the less collisions.

Comment: buckets is total records * total records

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What your code boils down to :

```
hash =  31 + nombre.hashCode();
```

If your string would be same then you would get collision.
You should change this to be more meaningful.

```
public int hashCode(String nombre )  {
    int hash = new Random().nextInt(); // PLEASE NOTE YOU SHOULD NOT CREATE NEW RANDOM EVERY TIME. CREATE IT ONCE AND JUST USE nextInt()
    hash =  hash*31 + nombre.hashCode();
    System.out.println("hsh " +hash);
    return Math.abs(hash);
}
```

Comment: if then I want to retrieve the record with the same hash function, I will return the different new Random().nextInt();  ?